# Android: launch any activity to start in the background?

Tags: android, background, apk, foreground

If I'm writing my own Android app, I know how to structure it as a Service so it will start running in the background.

However, is there a way to launch an existing app (for example, any random .apk from the Play Store) so that it starts up in the background, without its screen taking over the display?

Alternatively, I'd be willing to launch the app, force it into the background, and redisplay the window of the previous app (whatever it might have been) that was running in the foreground. I don't know how to programmatically put the current app in the background and then determine the previous app and bring it back to the foreground.

I'm willing to do this any way possible: via Java, via one or more command-line utilities, via a Tasker plugin, via an Xposed module, or whatever.

Thank you in advance for any pointers to docs or any suggestions.

Comment: "is there a way to launch an existing app (for example, any random .apk from the Play Store) so that it starts up in the background, without its screen taking over the display?" -- if you really are asking if you can start an arbitrary activity from an existing app (e.g., its launcher activity) without that activity taking over the foreground, the answer is no. "I don't know how to programmatically put the current app in the background..." -- call `startActivity()` to start up some other activity.

Comment: ".. determine the previous app and bring it back to the foreground" -- this is not possible on newer versions of Android, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is no way in modern versions of Android to figure out the previous activity that had been ocupying the screen, so I could then invoke it via startActivity()? Isn't there even any way from the command line to query which activity is currently in the foreground?

Comment: You can't even tell the *app* that was previously in the foreground. Even if you could, you have no way of identifying the specific activity, and for most activities, you have no way of actually starting it, since they are not exported. " Isn't there even any way from the command line to query which activity is currently in the foreground?" -- on a development machine, possibly.

Comment: Not even the #0 entry of "dumpsys activity recents"? I just discovered that.

Comment: On a development machine, yes. On a rooted device, possibly -- that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: I have a rooted, non-development device, so "dumpsys activity recents"  will serve my purpose. I agree that this might not work on a standard, non-rooted device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the #0 entry of "dumpsys activity recents" gives the currently displayed activity ... at least on my rooted Marshmallow device. This gives me what I need.